# Ubuntu server 16.04 - Get full FTP access to /var/www/

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-httpd, ftp

I've created a user 'www' and added it to the 'www-data' group. I've set the home directory of 'www' to /var/www/ also. I would like to use 'www' to transfer files in and out of my web server by FTP

The problem is when I run the command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
```

..I don't have permission to write files via FTP

However when I run:

```
sudo chown -R www:www /var/www
```

..I have full FTP access but get a 'Forbidden' message in my browser.

Any advice on how to get full FTP access **including all subfolders** would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that you already have a www-data user which Apache uses that should have the necessary permissions in `/var/www`.

The simplest solution would be to use that same user, but you could also assign the `www-data` group to your new user and make sure the `/var/www` directory structure allows the group to write to it:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
chmod -R ug+rw /var/www
```

Comment: 'chmod -R ug+rw /var/www' did the trick. You've saved me a massive headache. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I've found out that PHP files are returning a HTTP 500 error code. 'Permission denied' in apache logs. HTML files are fine.. just PHP. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the directories holding them don't give +x to the Apache user.